# Deploy ArcGIS Mobile App Without AGMRuntime.CAB

Tags: arcgis-9.3, arcgis-mobile

I want to deploy my ArcGIS Mobile app to a Windows Mobile device but I don't want users to deal with installing the AGMRuntime.CAB. I tried just adding the following dlls to my project:

```
ESRIMobileCore.dll
ESRIMobileGPS.dll
ESRIMobileSdc.dll
pe.dll
ESRI.ArcGIS.Mobile.dll
```

but I still keep getting this error:

```
Missing ArcGIS registry key.
```

on this line of code

```
 this.map1 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Mobile.Map();
```

when I run my application in the Windows Mobile Emulator through Visual Studio 2008. Anyone knows if I'm doing something that's imposible?

**Update**

I found a sample application [here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1fd18ced12604ba2a42f97644e2f6c9e) that does this for ArcGIS Mobile 9.3. I haven't had time to try this for 10.